# JUnit 5 test Mockito for RefreshToken

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, mapper

**Below is the code**

@Service
public class RefreshTokenServiceImpl implements RefreshTokenService {

```
@Autowired
private RefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository;

@Override

public RefreshToken generateRefreshToken() {

RefreshTokenEntity tokenEntity = new RefreshTokenEntity();

tokenEntity.setToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

tokenEntity.setCreatedDate(Instant.now());


tokenEntity = refreshTokenRepository.save(tokenEntity);

return RefreshTokenBeanMapper.REFRESH_TOKEN_BEAN_MAPPER.refreshTokenEntityToModel(tokenEntity);
}
```

**RefreshToken**

```
public class RefreshToken {


private Long id;


private String token;

private Instant createdDate;
}
```

**RefreshTokenBeanMapper**

```
@Mapper

public interface RefreshTokenBeanMapper {

RefreshTokenBeanMapper REFRESH_TOKEN_BEAN_MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(RefreshTokenBeanMapper.class);

RefreshToken refreshTokenEntityToModel(RefreshTokenEntity refreshTokenEntity);

}
```

**Trying to write a suitable JUnit 5 Mockito test**

Comment: Please understand: you are asking fellow humans to spend their time to help you for free. So you please take the 5, 10 minutes it takes to learn how to properly format your code input here using the markdown language so that your input is human readable. Also note: dont use empty lines in your code just so. Any character in programming matters. Too many (or not enough) empty lines affect readability, too. Use empty lines and indenting wisely!

Comment: Besides that, it is really not clear what you are asking for. Which functionality is it that you explicitly want to test here?

Comment: Thank you for formatting your code. Can you please add some information about what you are asking? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you need always generate the only one UUID and Date for yours token testing. For this, you can use experimental mockito-inline which  contains functionality for static methods.

I guess you need something like this:

```
UUID testUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
Instant n = Instant.now();
    try {
      MockedStatic<UUID> uuid = Mockito.mockStatic(UUID.class)
      uuid.when(UUID::randomUUID).thenReturn(testUUID);
      MockedStatic<Instant> inst = Mockito.mockStatic(Instant.class)
      inst.when(Instant::now).thenReturn(n);
      ...
}
    ...
```

https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods